# scroll within a scrollable element with webdriver-io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

How do you scroll within a scrollable element with webdriver-io?
I have tried the following code:

```
client
.scroll('#hierarchy_p')
.scroll(20, 50);
```

Or

```
client
.scroll('#hierarchy_p', 20, 50);
```

But neither of them have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I wouln't advice using `driver.executeScript`, but until something like `webElement.setAttribute` comes up, I doubt that there are many other ways of doing this.

for scrolling up and down a scrollable element:

```
function scrollToFn(driver, element, scrollAmount){
    return elem.getAttribute('scrollTop').then(function(val){
        scrollAmount += +val;       // written as +val for string to number conversion
        return driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1]", elem, scrollAmount);
    });
}
```

for scrolling to particular element inside scrollable element:

```
function scrollToInnerFn(driver, parentEle, innerEle){
    return innerEle.getAttribute('offsetTop').then(function(val){
        return driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1]", parentEle, val);
    });
}
```

*Note*: both the above functions would be returning a promise.

usage

```
...
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var browser1 = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer().withCapabilities({
    browserName: 'firefox'
}).build();
...

var elem = browser1.findElement(webdriver.By.css('#scrollT'));
var elem2 = browser1.findElement(webdriver.By.css('#mm'));
scrollToFn(browser1, elem, 200).then(function(){
    scrollToInnerFn(browser1, elem, elem2);
}).then(...
```

Comment: Do you have webdriverio solution?

Answer (score 1):

The `scrollTop` approach did not work for my use case. This is what worked:

```
browser.execute(function() {
    document.querySelector('#hierarchy_p').scrollIntoView();
});
```

This is using webdriver.io v4.14.0 testing in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but I had the same problem. The examples given by @mido are quite complex and I had hard time understanding them, so I found a simple way to do this.

We have to use the **[.execute()](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/execute.html)** command:

```
browser.execute([function(){},param1,param2,....]);
```

You want to scroll down inside the scroll-able element, so let's suppose your container is a `div` with id `id='scrollContent_body'`. Now all you have to do is use below the snipped presented bellow:

```
browser.execute(function() {
    // browser context - you may not access client or console
    // += 60 will scroll down
    // -= 60 will scroll up
    document.getElementById('scrollContent_body').scrollTop += 60;
});
```

**Note:** It does not matter weather your driver is `browser`, or `client`.